# Converting string to datetime based on IF Statement

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL Query that pulls IT Project change history out of our project management system.

The SQL table I'm working with has 3 columns in question. All are string format.

```
**COLUMNNAME**      **PREV_VALUE**      **CURRENT_VALUE**
Userid                NULL                Smith, John
Statusid              Horizon             Open
Projectedend          1541217540000       1542862740000
```

The COLUMNAME field is telling me what field changed on the particular record.  The other two fields are just the actual changes for previous value and the new value.

I need to write an IF Statement that says IF COLUMNAME = *Date Field Change* (projectedend in the above example) THEN convert the number (which again is technically a string) in to a US Date format.

When working with normal DATE fields in this database, I would just use the following SQL line to change the format.

```
DATEADD(second, prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE / 1000, '1970-01-01')
```

But because these fields are STRING format, I'm getting an error when trying to write my SQL Query. ***Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.***

The query I've been working with:

```
SELECT 
    prj.[PROJECTID],
    prj.[TITLE],
    prj.[OWNERID],
    prjhst.HISTORYID,
    prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME,
    prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE,

    CASE
        WHEN prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME = 'Projectedend' THEN DATEADD(second, prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE / 1000, '1970-01-01')
        ELSE prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE
    END AS 'Previous Value',

    prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME

  FROM [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectDetails] prj
  LEFT JOIN [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectHistory] prjhst on prj.PROJECTID = prjhst.PROJECTID
  LEFT JOIN [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectHistoryDiff] prjhstdif on prjhst.HISTORYID = prjhstdif.HISTORYID
```

I've also tried various forms of CONVERT and PARSE including the TRY_ variants but I'm either getting errors or NULLs.

Any assistance you could provide with my Query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your column prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE to a BIGINT inside your DATEDIFF. See if this query works for you.

```
SELECT 
    prj.[PROJECTID],
    prj.[TITLE],
    prj.[OWNERID],
    prjhst.HISTORYID,
    prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME,
    prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE,

    CASE
        WHEN prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME = 'Projectedend' THEN DATEADD(second, CAST(prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE AS BIGINT) / 1000, '1970-01-01')
        ELSE prjhstdif.PREV_VALUE
    END AS 'Previous Value',

    prjhstdif.COLUMNNAME

  FROM [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectDetails] prj
  LEFT JOIN [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectHistory] prjhst on prj.PROJECTID = prjhst.PROJECTID
  LEFT JOIN [sdp].[dbo].[ProjectHistoryDiff] prjhstdif on prjhst.HISTORYID = prjhstdif.HISTORYID
```